# Question get truncated before posting?

Tags: feature-request, support, automatic-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

I don't know if this is a known rule yet, but I just tried to post a question beginning with "Hi friends,xyz....".

Automatically, when I posted that question, the post appeared as usual, but the part: "hi friends" disappeared, and only "xyz..." remained.

If that is a known rule (about don't begin the question with "hi everyone" stuff), I think it should be made clearer by notification.

Here's the mentioned question: [Get user login status on Facebook by real time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035687/get-user-login-status-on-facebook-by-real-time)

Comment: This is absolutely not a duplicate. "If that is a known rule, I think it should be make clearer by notification."

Comment: Yeah, for some reason we're very opposed to notifications around here. Some 50% of the recent questions posted to Meta seem to request *more* notifications. You do have to find the right balance of signal and noise, though. Notifying you any time that something happened automatically would be annoying; that's why we do it automatically in the first place. But I suppose some things *are* worth notifying users over so that they're not surprised by the outcome and tempted to come report a bug. Finding that balance is the difficult part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**, there is a [known rule](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) that you shouldn't use signatures, taglines, or salutations in your posts.

And **yes**, they're being [automatically removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989) now upon submission of your question. This saves time of people who would have to edit your question to manually remove this greeting.

The best thing to do is to work to *eliminate* the superfluous "noise" in your question, rather than fretting too much over its disappearance.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I just think it will be better to have some kind of notification. If the posts get truncated automatically, sometimes (in my case), the remaining part is incomplete & silly